# Can't download pdf with java

Tags: java, pdf, download

I'm trying to download a file from 
http://aula.au.dk/main/document/document.php?action=download&id=%2F%D8velsesvejledning+2012.pdf
but it dosen't appear to be a pdf, when i try downloading it with this code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DownloadFile {

public static void download(String address, String localFileName) throws IOException {
    URL url1 = new URL(address);

    byte[] ba1 = new byte[1024];
    int baLength;
    FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(localFileName);

    try {
        // Contacting the URL
        System.out.print("Connecting to " + url1.toString() + " ... ");
        URLConnection urlConn = url1.openConnection();

        // Checking whether the URL contains a PDF
        if (!urlConn.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf")) {
            System.out.println("FAILED.\n[Sorry. This is not a PDF.]");
        } else {
            try {

                // Read the PDF from the URL and save to a local file
                InputStream is1 = url1.openStream();
                while ((baLength = is1.read(ba1)) != -1) {
                    fos1.write(ba1, 0, baLength);
                }
                fos1.flush();
                fos1.close();
                is1.close();


            } catch (ConnectException ce) {
                System.out.println("FAILED.\n[" + ce.getMessage() + "]\n");
            }
        }

    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        System.out.println("FAILED.\n[" + npe.getMessage() + "]\n");
    }
}
}
```

Can you help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

http://aula.au.dk/main/document/document.php?action=download&id=%2F%D8velsesvejledning+2012.pdf is not a pdf. The website gives an error this is why the script doesn't work:

> SQL error in file /data/htdocs/dokeos184/www/main/inc/tool_navigation_menu.inc.php at line 70

Comment: Seems like there was an error on the site. If you click the link now, you're just about to download a pdf. Do you know how i get to download this file? If i us the getContentType() i get 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-15'

Answer (score 0):

As Marti said, the root cause of the problem is the fact that the script fails.  I tested your program on a working pdf link, it works just fine.

This wouldn't have helped you in this case, but [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) is a specialized subclass of URLConnection that makes communications with an http server a lot easier - eg direct access to error codes, etc.

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
// check the responsecode for e.g. errors (4xx or 5xx) 
int responseCode = urlConn.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 0):

**2 step process with 2 libraries.**

```
// 1. Use Jsoup to get the response.
Response response= Jsoup.connect(location)
                   .ignoreContentType(true)
                   // more method calls like user agent, referer, timeout 
                   .execute();

// 2. Use Apache Commons to write the file 
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(path), response.bodyAsBytes());
```